# AdActivity not being declared in manifest......but I am using sdk v 3?

Tags: android, android-manifest, admob

There are numerous helpful posts regarding this topic but all require me to use a later sdk than I have written my app for.In an effort to make my app as backwards compatible as possible I chose to create it using Android 1.5 (sdk v 3). 
With the code suggested for declaring the manifest I have some issues with eclipse giving me an error as the code refers to later sdk functions not available in Android 1.5

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
        />
```

Eclipse is telling me that everything after orientation is the problem.

```
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction insofar as code for the manifest or how to compile for a later target?

Cheers!!

Ok.....here is the code from the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ohmywebdesign.trigsolver"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="1.3" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <meta-data android:value="YOURPUBIDHERE" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Rick, the question is, why would you want to compile against an outdated sdk version?

Comment: This is my first app and I wanted to make it available to all android users. Am I barking up the wrong tree with this line of thinking or is there a better way? I am open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: I'd like to tell you that not many people on this planet are sticking to 1.5 or 1.6. Even most of the manufacturers are building phones that support 2.2 and higher. I think you can aim for 2.1, i.e. sdk version 7. Suggest you to watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxU8N21wfrM&feature=player_embedded

Comment: @Rick: Why do you want to handle all of those configuration changes yourself?

Comment: Thank you for the link Ghost. You point is well received and as such I have upgraded to 2.1
Alas my problem still persists in that I am still receiving the error mentioned above.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: To be honest I would rather not be making any of these changes. This is my first time trying to implement AdMob into my app and all the tutorials and Stack posts are suggesting as such.
I will add the bulk of my manifest code below for anyone to pick through.

Comment: @Rick: Firstly don't use `android:maxSdkVersion` it's genaerally not recommended. Secondly you're targetting API 8 and a couple of those `configChanges` values are for API 13 onwards. Drop the `android:maxSdkVersion` and up the `android:targetSdkVersion` to 13 and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Rick: Just to clarify - when I say "Drop the android:maxSdkVersion" I mean get rid of it rather than 'lower the number'.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: maxSdk has been dropped and targetSdk bumped up to 13 and then again to 14 and 15......same resulting error :(

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html , i think you need to override onConfigurationChanged()

Comment: @Venky: Thanks for the suggestion but does this actually address the error I am receiving from eclipse in regards to the attributes of the configChanges in the manifest?
        
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').

Comment: It's a common usege to now support outdated version of android for your and user's mental sanity :D

Old version has bugs, less features and are slower than newest. 
I think that at the moment the the min SDK to support is for Android 2.1 (remember that 2.2 is more than 85% of overall android)

Comment: All the rumblings about which version developers should target are irrelevant to the question, honestly. The best resource to use when choosing your minimum SDK is, in my opinion, <http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html>. However, if a developer decides they want to target 1.5 as a minimum, that's their own choice that they're free to make. After all, if you're not going to be using any API features introduced in later levels (e.g. the external storage functions from 2.2), why limit your install base for no gain?

Comment: @RickShaw: Try Rebuilding the entire project, Rick. I don't really know what else to suggest you if nothing among all these solutions seems to be working.

Comment: @Ghost: Yeah that is pretty much what I had to do. On top of all that I had some issues with the Android SDK and had to reinstall that.
Thank you all for your help with this one!!

Comment: @RickShaw: You're welcome Rick.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="15" />
```

In you manifest will allow you to do what you want.

Also, be sure you have the latest AdMob SDK ie version 4.3.1 http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/download.html

and that you include

```
<meta-data android:value="YOURPUBIDHERE" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
```

Comment: Initially I had issues with referencing the sdk versions 8 & 15 which I overcame by switching my build to Android 1.6
But even then I still have the issue of eclipse calling the configChanges string as an error.

Comment: Then, I would make sure you are using the latest AdMob SDK ie version 4.3.1 http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/download.html - updated my answer.

Comment: @TryTryAgain: Don't recommend using `android:maxSdkVersion` attribute. The Android dev guide doesn't recommend it. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

As MisterSquonk's comment on the question stated, some of the `configChanges` values were introduced in API levels higher than that of 1.5. Merely changing the values of the minimum/target/maximum API levels in the manifest alone won't solve your issue, you have to make sure to *build* against an SDK level that declares those values.

For Ant-based builds, this would entail altering the `target` property's value in `project.properties`; I don't use Eclipse for my Android projects, so I'm not 100% sure, but here's an excerpt from the [Eclipse/ADT documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#CreatingAProject) that seems relevant to what you'd need to do:

> Note: You can change your the Build Target for your project at any time: Right-click the project in the Package Explorer, select **Properties**, select **Android** and then check the desired Project Target.

Of course, if you do this, you have to ensure not to directly use any classes/methods from API levels higher than your minimum, or your application will fail at runtime when run on devices implementing lower API levels.

Remember, the manifest is only used at runtime on the device (and by most distribution channels, such as the Android Market). The build target is something completely separate which is used at compile-time.